# Auto adjust windows application screen size according to screen resolution

Tags: wpf, xamarin.wpf

I'm currently making an application which contains 1 window and many similar formatted page (width = 800, height = 450).

If I don't define the minwidth and minheight then the screen looks like this(below image) and If I define minwidth and minheight(1000,650) then the screen is not fitting to all screen resolutions(In small resolution laptops the screen is cutting).

[image]

How can I make the window fit to screen resolution with minimum of width and height as(70%,70%)of screen resolution.

I've tried using **this.sizetocontent=SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight** but no use.Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Screen size

```
Width =System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```

setting 70% as min size

```
MinWidth=70* width / 100 ;
MinHeight=70* height / 100 ;
```